# Webdriver project setup with c# visual studio

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I new to webdriver with c# and visual studio as I used to work with java.

I would like to know while creating project what type should I chose; either console application or class library.

Because if I make the project type as Console application then I should put main method as mandatory in any one of the class. But I don't want to use main method since I would create Unit Test project along with the solution.

And to simulate to project setup as with java and eclipse, and with Page object model which project or application type would be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends. Both will fit.

If you would like to automate a navigation, I'd recommend Console App. If you want to check if your page was rendered correctly, I'd recommend Unit Test Project.

Comment: Ok, but if i use a console app then I should have a main function in some class, so if I don't want to use main function at all, then is it okay to use class library? Because compiling a class library will always gives a dll and not exe. But hope dll or exe shouldn't matter when we run the test setup from tcm. Please correct me if am wrong.